# Multiple Material UI AppBar CSS conflict Caused By Postion Prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two Material UI AppBars in my application. The first appbar is part of the layout of the page and appears first. However whenever the second one appears, it adds an additional style tag to the page which messes up the first AppBar and hence the page. The second AppBar is:

```
<AppBar position="static" color="default>
```

and the CSS it adds is like this:

```
<style data-jss data-meta="MuiAppBar>...</style>
```

Now there is already a style element in the header with the same CSS rules which get overridden by this.
I have tried using withStyle and className and putting the **position prop** as CSS to isolate the CSS rules for the second AppBar, however to no avail as the issue is with the props. What is the standard way of handling this? thanks.

**Edit 1:**
Upon revisiting the two components which are making use of AppBar I realized something. One was imported like this:

```
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar/index'
```

and the other:

```
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'
```

When I removed the `'/index'` from the first, then it got fixed.
Can someone explain what is going on here? thanks.

Comment: A working codpen or jsfiddle example will be easy to debug

Comment: Pulling in a second AppBar element should not cause additional MuiAppBar styles to be added to the `<head>`. The main reasons that would happen would be if one occurs within a nested theme or if you are pulling in multiple copies of Material-UI and the two AppBar elements are being rendered by different instances of Material-UI. I recommend that you try to create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell you are right, the imports were not the same. care to explain what is going on here? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'` is the correct way to import the component.

From https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-1

> Be aware that we only support first and second level imports. Anything deeper is considered private and can cause issues, such as module duplication in your bundle.

Adding `/index` turns it into a third-level import and results in module duplication and thus duplication of the styles.